# Using AWS CP command can we upload local zip file to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
aws s3 --region cp XXX.zip s3://XXX --recursive --acl public-read
```

I am using above command to upload my local zip to s3 but not working

Comment: What is not working about it? Is there an error message? What platform are you on?

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am getting below error 
warning: Skipping file XX.zip/. File does not exist.

Comment: Are you including a region name after the --region flag? right now it reads  --region cp in your command above.

Comment: Yes i am including

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Ahh --recursive is the problem. It is causing the file name to become a directory which is not, it is a file. This sounds like a bug/annoyance. From the Docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) --recursive (boolean) Command is performed on all files or objects under the specified directory or prefix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`--recursive` flag is the problem. It is causing the filename to be interpreted as directory which is not, it is a file. This sounds like a bug/annoyance of the AWS command. 
From the Docs (docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

`--recursive` (boolean) Command is performed on all files or objects under the specified directory or prefix.

Remove `--recursive` and the file is copied

```
aws s3 --region us-east-1 cp XXX.zip s3://XXX --acl public-read
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.